# Looping through ListBox to enter values into sheet array

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to find the cells (or Rows) in Column B, Sheet1, who have matching values placed into ListBox2. Then, I'd like to change the value of a cell 4 columns over (using an Offset command).

I believe using a For loop is the most efficient way of going thru the values placed into ListBox2. I tried using a Forloop to go thru all values placed into ListBox2.List. Upon calling a value, the code would look for this value in Column B. Once found, it would "remember" the Row in which this value was found. Then, the code would use a Range/Offset command to change the value of a cell 4 columns over in that Row.

```
Private Sub ButtonOK_Click()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim SerialList As Range
    Dim SerialRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim strFind As Variant

With ws

    For i = 0 To Me.ListBox2.ListCount - 1

    Set SerialList = ws.Range("B:B").Find(What:=Me.ListBox2.List(i))
            SerialRow = SerialList.Row
            If Not SerialList Is Nothing Then
                ws.Range("B", SerialRow).Offset(0, 4).Value =     Me.ListBox2.List(i) 'error occurs here!
                MsgBox (ListBox2.List(i) & " found in row: " & SerialList.Row)
            Else
                MsgBox (ListBox2.List(i) & " not found")
            End If
    Next i

End With

End Sub
```

The MsgBoxes do say the correct ListBox2.List(i) value and the correct SerialList.Row, meaning that the program is correctly finding the row in which the list box value is located. However, I get an error saying that my range is not correctly defined at line "ws.Range("B", SerialRow)....."

How do I select the cell I'm searching for to correctly set it to =Me.ListBox2.List(i)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of fixes:

```
Dim lv

'....

For i = 0 To Me.ListBox2.ListCount - 1
    lv = Me.ListBox2.List(i)
    Set SerialList = ws.Range("B:B").Find(What:=lv, LookAt:=xlWhole) '<< be more explicit
    'don't try to access SerialList.Row before checking you found a match...     
    If Not SerialList Is Nothing Then
        ws.Cells(SerialList.Row, "F").Value = lv '<< Cells in place of Range
        MsgBox (lv & " found in row: " & SerialList.Row)
    Else
        MsgBox (lv & " not found")
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: Thank you Tim! Works like a charm. I'm still learning the small details!